# Deploying Asp.net MVC web application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

I have been trying to find a neat tutorial, guide or step by step instructions for deploying an Asp.net MVC3 webapp but have found nothing so far. Everyone talks about his version of the stroy and different type of MVC versions.

Right now, I have build a simple Asp.net MVC web application which i need to deploy on my shared hosting account. In a very simple manner, I need to know which files should i copy. Do i upload everything in my webproject directory to the server including the controller directory, views, models, content and bin directory ?. What about the Global.asax, web.config, packages.config, myapp.publish.xml.

In short, I have no idea which files should be uploaded and which should be not. I am sure of one thing that i need few(MVC and Razor dlls) following dlls in bin directory. Just treat me as someone who has never deployed any website

**NOTE:-** I don't have VS SP1 installed and it doesn't install either. Basically i need a manual procedure.

Comment: @ThanosPapathanasiou, nah ! that seems a bit advanced thing. Couldn't understand what OP was asking there.

Comment: If you don't have VS then the only way to compile&publish your site is through console. what was asked there is exactly what you want.

Comment: I have the VS installed but not the SP1 update...Sorry if i aid to your misunderstanding.

Comment: Sounds like to you need to fix your VS installation so that you can install SP1 and use web deploy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here is a tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410407%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) on the MSDN site about how to deploy an MVC application.  Typically, hosts will also now have WebDeploy available, which is a very easy way to deploy and update your application without having to worry about what files to copy.